# I try to connect in my databases Atlas MongoDB with flutter but it's does'nt work

Tags: flutter

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
//import '../datas/data.dart' as data;
import '../models/city_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class CityProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<City> _cities = [];
  UnmodifiableListView<City> get cities => UnmodifiableListView(_cities);

  City getCityByName(String cityName) =>
      cities.firstWhere((city) => city.name == cityName);

  fetchData() async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:80/api/cities');
      print(json.decode(response.body));
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

An Observatory debugger and profiler on TECNO KA7 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:56141/qSlaCfRC08A=/
E/flutter (19000): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 45965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a problem with android debug bridge.
You can try

```
adb reverse tcp:<Port on your phone> tcp:<Port on your computer>
```

Comment: I fixed the probleme. Thanks so much, I used the Ip of my boxe-wifi 192.168.1.1 :80

Comment: Glad I can help.
If my answer did fix your problem, you should mark it as the correct answer. @MamadouLamineBOUSSO